# I need to calculate the direction for mid air collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, collision

I have two objects in 3D world without gravity, let's say two spaceships A and B and Ship B need to catch to ship A. Both ships have initial velocities different from each other. Ship B got thrusters so it has an acceleration to a direction of our choice. The question is what should be the direction of the acceleration to catch ship A.

As it's not a book-like question it's hard to find with formulas I should use or even what to look for, any advice will be appreciated.

Edit: Max acceleration for the ship B is 10m/sec

Comment: The best way to do this by hand would be in the perspective of ship A. (Add a relative velocity component to ship B and make sure the distance goes to zero). But I do think the question needs more clarity to be answered. Where are you stuck?

Comment: No that will create a curved way to ship A, I want a linear way to where ship A will be in the future with the acceleration of ship B. I am stuck on what to use as all the examples I saw are in a one-dimensional plane and don't have a direction to their acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, the problem has infinitely many possible solutions. This is because the unknown acceleration has three components, and time makes it four unknowns, but there are only three equations - one for each of the Cartesian components.

If you can narrow the problem down to requiring interception to occur after a specified period of time, then you can find a *constant* acceleration $\underline{f}$ required by equating the position vectors of the two particles. These would take the form:
$$\underline{a}=\underline{a}_0+t\underline{v}_A$$
$$\underline{b}=\underline{b}_0+t\underline{v}_B+\frac12\underline{f}t^2$$

in this formulation:

$\underline{a}$ is the position vector of A at time $t$

$\underline{b}$ is the position vector of B at time $t$

$\underline{a}_0$ and $\underline{b}_0$ are their initial positions at time $t=0$

$\underline{v}_A$ and $\underline{v}_B$ are their initial vecocities at time $t=0$

and $\underline{f}$ is the acceleration of B (assumed constant)

If the acceleration is variable, then again the possibilities are endless.

Comment: Ah, I see, alright let's say that the thrusters max acceleration is 10m/sec. As I said before we need to get the direction of the acceleration so that ship B will catch ship A. And the ships are in 3D space so they aren't linear with where I find the problem challenging.

Comment: So if you assign the value $10$ to the magnitude of the acceleration that gives you an extra equation which will enable you to solve the system. You can get each component of acceleration in terms of $t$ and solve an equation for $t$ first. The fact that it's 3 dimensional doesn't change the method - you just have an extra unknown to deal with.

Comment: I see, well let me try this. Can you help me out here I didn't use physics functions in years what are the small b and f represent?

Comment: See my edited answer. You need to try out some actual values to see how it works.

Comment: This is the answer, I looked at it wrongly I was trying to find acceleration direction and didn't understand how to do so. All I needed is to find Ships A location at the time of the collision and from that all I needed to simply calculate the direction from Ship B location to Ship A end location.